# Include list items in SharePoint workflow notification

Tags: email, workflow

The sharepoint environment i work has some restricted functionality. What I want to achieve is to send out alerts or notifications whenever a new list item is created to an email. Trouble is we want to send it to a common mailbox and not an individual so the alert feature is of no help as sharepoint will not be able to find the email. I can use the workflow feature but it will send the link to the list (customizing the email body) but if the person doesn't have access to the site then its of no use.

Is there a way by which I can use the built in workflow feature to send the list items in the notification email without using designer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the issue you bring up regarding having the workflow sending a link to the e-mail address being of no use if the persons receiving it don't have access to the site. That'll be an issue regardless of how the mail is send.

Of solutions to send out email when an item is created I can see the following:

1. Create a dummy user in AD with the email address set to the email-group. Then log in as that user and setup alerts (or do it as site collection owner)
2. Create a SharePoint designer workflow starting on item created sending out the email
3. Create an EventReceiver for ItemAdded sending out the email
4. Set up a three state workflow workflow to be started and assigning a dummy task to nobody (or someone who can clean up these dummy tasks) and sending an email to the group. This will create odd dummy tasks and is only included to give the requested possibility of doing it with OOTB workflows
5. Use a third party tool (Bing/google for "SharePoint alert manage")